# qTip 2 tip size issue

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I've looked at the documentation and applied relevant configs where required. I'm just bit baffled as to why the width of the tip seems to be only applied to the outer element and the canvas div inside is a different width / remains default size (applies as inline styles) creating this arrow below. Works fine on arrows postioned on the side of tooltip but not on the top and bottom.

[image]

```
$('.social li a').qtip({ 
    style: {
        tip: {
            width: 20,
            height: 10
        }
    },
    ...etc
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=4375

Found a link from the qtip developer forum to include the nightly build and this fixed the issue.